# How to call a method with parameters?

Tags: java, methods, invoke

I'm trying to get the return value savedName from calling the method. 
I need to use the value from the string saved name in another method

```
    if (n == 0){
        String fullName = readFromFile(); //wont let me do this
        text.setText("Welcome " + fullName + ".");
    }


private String readFromFile(String savedName){
    savedName="";
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
    savedName = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(savedName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return savedName;

}
```

Comment: simply do this `String fullName = readFromFile("your string");`

Comment: You need to read this
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are trying to call must have a matching method signature.  In this case the number and type arguments must be the same.  The most direct approach is to remove the String argument from your method, and create a String variable called savedName in your method and return it, like this:

```
private String readFromFile(){
    String savedName="";
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
    savedName = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(savedName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return savedName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have made new changes in `String fullName = readFromFile("pass some String here"); //wont let me do this`

```
 if (n == 0){
        String fullName = readFromFile("pass some String here"); //now this will let you do
        text.setText("Welcome " + fullName + ".");
    }


private String readFromFile(String savedName){
    savedName="";
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
    savedName = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(savedName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return savedName;

}
```